# JS: Как правильно обратиться к ссылке? <a href="#project_info">

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Есть кнопка в меню шапки:

```html
<li class="nav-item">
   <a href="#project_info" class="nav-link" id="project_info">О ПРОЕКТЕ</a>
</li>
```

Пытаюсь обратиться к этой кнопке, но браузер её не читает, видимо, я не правильно к ней обращаюсь:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('project_info');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Вы кликнули по кнопке');
});
```

Не кидайте в меня тапками, пожалуйста, я новичок. В чем моя ошибка? Как надо правильно обратиться к такой ссылке?

Спасибо!

Comment: Проверил - всё работает.

Comment: Перенести script куда-нибудь ниже, чтобы загружался после создания `<a>`

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, ваша ошибка заключается в том, что Ваш код загрузился раньше, чем "появилась" кнопка, т.к. браузер рендерит страницу ["каскадом"](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Performance/How_browsers_work#%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3), он мог "прочитать" скрипт, обратиться к кнопке, а её ещё нет.

Первый способ решить эту проблему: Поместить скрипт в конец (обычно перед закрывающимся тегом `body`.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <a id="#project_info"></a> <!-- Та самая кнопка -->
  <script></script> <!-- Тот самый скрипт -->
</body>
</html>
```

Второй вариант, запустить скрипт после "получения" всей страницы.
Тут месторасположение самого скрипта может быть где угодно, код начнёт выполнятся после получения всего кода страницы браузером, для этого есть слушатель [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded)

В `script`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let button = document.querySelector('#project_info');
  
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert('Вы кликнули по кнопке');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код работал исправно.
Нажмите кнопку ниже "Выполнить код" и кликните на ссылку "О проекте", чтобы убедиться.

```js
let button = document.querySelector('#project_info');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert('Вы кликнули по кнопке');
});
```

```html
<li class="nav-item">
   <a href="#project_info" class="nav-link" id="project_info">О ПРОЕКТЕ</a>
</li>
```